# TypeError: dart.global.FacebookAuth is not a constructor

Tags: flutter, facebook-authentication

Getting this error while adding `flutter_facebook_auth` package to your Flutter web app:
`TypeError: dart.global.FacebookAuth is not a constructor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the top of your body tag

```
  <script>
      var FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID";
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: "v9.0",
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };
    </script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" ></script>
    <script src="flutter_facebook_auth.js" type="application/javascript" ></script>
```

See: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth#add-support-for-flutter-web